# Countdown timer with user input to set time c#

Tags: c#, timer, countdown

I am trying to build a countdown timer that if the selected choice is set time, it will open and prompts the user to enter value to set the time. once the user is done in typing the numbers, it must show choices like this

Press S to start: Press P to pause

This is what I am lacking, I do not know what to code to enable to pause the time and to start it.

```
using System;
namespace time_console

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            designNumbers Fancy = new designNumbers();
            Program mainMenu = new Program();
            mainMenu.RunMainMenu();
        }
        
        private void RunMainMenu()
        {
            string prompt = "Welcome to Neil's Countdown Timer. Select an option";
            string[] options = { "Set Time", "Exit" };
            Menu mainMenu = new Menu(prompt, options);
            int selectedIndex = mainMenu.Run();

            switch (selectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    SetTime();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Exit();
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        private void SetTime()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("enter time in minutes:seconds ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 5);
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 6);
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (; ; )
            {
                if (s == 0 && m == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nTime's up!");break;
                }
                if (s == 0)
                {
                    s = 60;
                    m--; 
                }
                System.Console.Clear();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 7);
                Console.WriteLine(m + ":" + s--);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            
            WriteLine("Press M to return to Menu");
            ConsoleKey a;
            ConsoleKeyInfo b = ReadKey(true);
            a = b.Key;
            
            if(a == ConsoleKey.M)
            {
                RunMainMenu();
            }

        }
        
        private void Exit()
        {
            WriteLine("press any key to exit...");
            ReadKey(true);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the key just as you are doing for Menu?

Comment: Confused about how you ask the user for "mm:ss" but then read input separately. Why not get them to type 12:34, split it on the colon and then parse the 12 and the 34 that you acquired, in one hit ?

Comment: In your loop that is doing the timing, check the boolean prop Console.KeyAvailable. If one is available read it. If it's a P and your timer is running, pause it (flip a boolean that is used to determine if to decrement the timer). If it's an S and your timer is not running, start it

Comment: uhmm, how sir? sorry, I'm just a student and new to c# if it was ++ I may have chance

Comment: Do I need to create a new private void for pause and start and then call it on the setTime class? sir Caius?